# Angular - Passing one component as parameter to another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In a dummy `Angular` application I have two components: `counter` and `test01`. As you can see on the [repository file](https://github.com/napolev/napolev.pr03/blob/master/src/app/app.html#L9)

This GitHub repository contains a totally working example.

Please, check this image.

[image: this image.]

If you click the button: "Change Counter Value" it sets the counter number to: 8 successfully.

But my question is: how could I pass the `counter` component to the `test01` component to change the value from inside a `test01` method in an easier way?

Right now the logic of the component: `test01` is more difficult as you can see [here](https://github.com/napolev/napolev.pr03/blob/master/src/components/test01/test01.component.ts)

I would like to do something like:

```
test01_obj.counter = 8;
```

with no too much code more.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the problem in the wrong way.

I suggest you to share the model (the count) between the two components instead and rely on bindings to achieve [indirect] interaction.

i.e.:

```
 export class ContainerComponent {

   myCounterModel: CounterModel = {
       count: 0
   };
   ...
 }

export class CounterComponent {
    ...
    @Input()
    counter: CounterModel;
}

export class Test01Component {
    ...
    @Input()
    counter: CounterModel;
}


  //ContainerComponent template

<counter [(counter)]="myCounterModel"></counter>
<hr />
<test01 [(counter)]="myCounterModel" [resetValue]="8"></test01>
```

Makes sense?

Comment: then, where do I declare: `let model: CounterModel`, in an independent file? or some of the already existing files?

Comment: In the container component for instance, please check the updated code snippet